# How to copy specific slides of one PowerPoint presentation to another?

Tags: c#, .net, com, powerpoint

I have below code using which trying to copy specific slides of one presentation to another but its not happening neither i am getting any error.

```
source = ppt.Presentations.Open(filename, MsoTriState.msoTrue, 
MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

target = ppt.Presentations.Open(targetname, MsoTriState.msoTrue, 
MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

sourceSlideRange = source.Slides.Count;

for (int i = 3; i < sourceSlideRange; i++)
{
source.Slides[i].Copy();
target.Windows[1].Activate();
target.Slides[1].Select();

target.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting");
}
```

What's wrong in my code? Please suggest.Thanks

Comment: @mjwillis 'sourceSlideRange' is 5 and target.slides.counts is 1

Comment: @Laria When you debug through your code, line by line, what happens? How many times does the `for` loop execute? Does https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e33dd7de-4dd6-42eb-8830-d74392e3319d/problem-with-powerpoint-method-commandbarsexecutemsoquotpastesourceformattingquot?forum=officegeneral sound like your issue?

Comment: @mjwillis it executes 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my requirement was to keep only specific slides in presentation, and my copying code posted was not working, so i tried to delete the unwanted slides from presentation keeping just the ones that i needed. Below is the code that solved the purpose

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppt = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
ppt.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
ppt.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized;

source = ppt.Presentations.Open(filename);

target = ppt.Presentations.Open(targetname, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

sourceSlideRange = source.Slides.Count;

for (int i = 3; i < sourceSlideRange; i++)
    {
      source.Slides[i].Delete();
      source.Save();

    }

source.Close();
```